# Twilio get international calls for current month

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

Is there a way to query only international calls from Twilio REST API? https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters

Right now my best option seems to query all calls and then parse each one of them to get country code and then filter calls where `countryTo != countryFrom`. Any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

No, you cannot filter by international calls via the API. Your method of filtering your list yourself is your best bet.